# Load values from Entity Framework into textboxes

Tags: wpf, frameworks, textbox, entity

I am writing a wpf application which pulls data from a sql db.

Currently I'm using the following code to populate a couple of text fields in my Window.

I would like to change this to get the data from the Entity Framework model (which I have implemented) instead of filling a dataset from a stored procedure first.

```
    // Initialize a new Data Set object
    DataSet dts = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // Call the DataManager Class which will collect the data and fill the dataset
    DataManager.SelectConsHead(dts);

    dt = dts.Tables[0];

    // Set the source of the listview
    foreach(DataRow drr in dt.Rows)
    {
        txtAccount.Text = drr["Consignee"].ToString();
        txtAccount_Printed.Text = drr["Consignee_Printed"].ToString();
        txtPostalAdd1.Text = drr["Postal_Add1"].ToString();
        txtPostalAdd2.Text = drr["Postal_Add2"].ToString();
        txtPostalAdd3.Text = drr["Postal_Add3"].ToString();
        txtPostalAdd4.Text = drr["Postal_Add4"].ToString();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to learn the Entity framework.

here you can learn by [videos provided by team](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620).

sample code.

```
 using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {
            // Create and save a new Blog
            Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Display all Blogs from the database
            var query = from b in db.Blogs
                        orderby b.Name
                        select b;

            Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```